# WCF scenario with least protection

Tags: wcf, activex-exe

I have written a WCF services that generates some messages.
These message should be retrieved by a different application.
Both run on one computer without network access.
In fact, I was trying to create something like an Active-X-exe in .NET.

I would like to make it so that the firewire is not involved and in such a way that I do not have to run the services with admin privileges.

I do not need any security.

However, I did not find one yet, but that may be due to the lack of my experience with WCF.

Can somebody recommand a binding that does not involve the firewall and which does not required admin privileges?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what you're saying, it sounds like you're looking for the pipe bindings since you're trying to communicate on the same machine.

Here's what they have to say about the pipe:

> NetNamedPipeBinding:
>
> A secure, reliable, optimized binding that is suitable for on-machine
>   communication between WCF applications.

I'm not too sure about the second part about the admin rights though.

You can have a look at all of the WCF options, taken from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx) if you want to look for something else, but the pipes will the fastest.

(you might want to look into msmq as well, but having no idea what exactly you're trying to do, it's hard to say).

Comment: NetNamedPipeBinding requires http or TCP. I have found out that http requires administrator privileges and TCP requires a firewall rule. So this does not really help me. Do you have any other suggestions for me? Thank you very much!

Comment: o_O? Why would it require HTTP or TCP ? Tcp is for remote (but same network) and Http is for internet (obviously, you can still use it for your own machine, but that's the idea). The whole point of pipes is that since it's on the same machine, you don't need none of the above.